# Is there a way to check if Android device screen is locked via adb?

Tags: android, adb

I know that PowerManager and/or KeyguardManager can help me check if a device screen is locked/unlocked. Is there a way to check this via adb?

Comment: ... and here is the counterpart for ios: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72825234/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-ios-device-screen-is-unlocked-via-command-line-on-mac

Comment: @ch271828n, that question has been removed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This command will output everything relating to power for the device:

```
adb shell dumpsys power
```

You can pipe this to a grep to get the values of `mHoldingWakeLockSuspendBlocker` and `mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker`:

```
adb shell dumpsys power | grep 'mHolding'
```

If both are false, the display is off.

If `mHoldingWakeLockSuspendBlocker` is false, and `mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker` is true, the display is on, but locked.

If both are true, the display is on.

Comment: I see mHoldingWakeLockSuspendBlocker changing value back and forth for several seconds after the device is unlocked, but it settles into WakeLock=false and Display=true even if the display remains unlocked.

Comment: Checking mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker is not reliable, e.g. if you run it right after pressing the power button to turning the display off this will still return true, there are some timing issues.

Comment: Please note than even though this is an accepted answer, the method described above will not work reliably - as pointed out in other comments. Both values will be false when screen is locked, but when the display is on, there's no relation.

Comment: if I want to use the second command for one device out of multiple,
in bash terminal its ok I just write 'adb -s $dev_number shell'...

Comment: Note this works on TCL 4 Google TV as well. Also note `'` quotes around `'mHolding'` are not necessary. Finally is it possible to show `adb` commands to set these values?

Answer (score 12):

Since Lollipop `PowerManager.isInteractive()` and `TrustManager.isDeviceLocked()` are the proper methods to check if the device's screen is on and unlocked.

And their corresponding `service call` commands would be:

```
adb shell service call power 12
```

and

```
adb shell service call trust 7
```

And this is how it can be checked from Python code without having to find Android version specific service call codes for your device - https://gist.github.com/ktnr74/60ac7bcc2cd17b43f2cb

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: Not sure what you want me to elaborate on. If you need help with parsing `service call` output - just make a new separate question. also read http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/calling-android-services-from-adb-shell.html

Comment: It sure isn't clear. Who does what? I just see that with screen on I get:
Result: Parcel(00000000 00000001   '........') and with screen off I get Result: Parcel(00000000 00000000   '........'). This with service call power 12. Thats what I should use?

Comment: wow this is a great find ! the answer selected as the best answer is flaky and sometimes returns true for both the variables while the screen is still unlocked while this is a true test! thanks a lot!

Comment: its really ugly, but the only thing working for me. service call power 12 works on Android 9/Pie too. But the values are reversed! screen_is_locked = "00000000 00000000" and screen_is_unlocked = "00000000 00000001"

Comment: This works for me like a charm. 

The method described above, marked as the correct answer, is not reliable. Use the @AlexP. approach instead.

Answer (score 11):

This works only when device has NFC:

```
# returns one of: mScreenState=OFF|ON_LOCKED|ON_UNLOCKED
adb shell dumpsys nfc | grep 'mScreenState='
```

OFF - Screen off

ON_LOCKED - Screen displays locked screen

ON_UNLOCKED - device unlocked

Comment: Can you believe, there's even `OFF_UNLOCKED`. Seen on a Samsung S10.

Comment: Same on Pixel 3 running Android 12, this is weird. And pressing power button will immediately put it to ```ON_LOCKED```
Why would they even transition to ```"OFF_UNLOCKED"``` when the display is dimmed?

Comment: This is the correct answer at 2022.

Answer (score 5):

Summry other (`@Vouskopes`, etc) answer here:

- My Phone: `XiaoMi 9`

  - Android: `10`

## use adb to check status of screen locked

### method 1: (universal) use `mDreamingLockscreen`

- Command: `adb shell dumpsys window | grep mDreamingLockscreen`
- Output:

  - `mShowingDream=false mDreamingLockscreen=true mDreamingSleepToken=null` -> Screen **Locked**

    - no matter Screen is `ON` or `OFF`
  - `mShowingDream=false mDreamingLockscreen=false mDreamingSleepToken=null` -> Scrren **Unlocked**

### method 2: use `nfc` (if android has NFC module)

- Command: `adb shell dumpsys nfc | grep 'mScreenState='`
- Output:

  - `mScreenState=OFF_LOCKED` -> Screen OFF and Locked
  - `mScreenState=ON_LOCKED` -> Screen ON and Locked
  - `mScreenState=ON_UNLOCKED` -> Screen ON and Unlocked

Answer (score 3):

Bryan's solution didn't work for my device (Samsung Galaxy S3 running version 4.4.2).

For my KitKat GS3:

- I can reliably tell if the screen is on by checking for `mScreenOn=true` (works regardless of screen lock state).
- I can reliably tell if screen is unlocked by checking for `mUserActivityTimeoutOverrideFromWindowManager=-1` (works regardless of screen ON or OFF).

---

If that doesn't work for you, I'd recommend you try the following:

1. Lock phone & turn off screen then run:

`adb shell dumpsys power > dumpsys.power.screen_off.locked.txt`

2. Wake phone & keep it locked then run:

`adb shell dumpsys power > dumpsys.power.screen_on.locked.txt`

3. Keep phone awake and unlock screen then run:

`adb shell dumpsys power > dumpsys.power.screen_on.unlocked.txt`

4. Turn screen off, but don't lock it then run:

`adb shell dumpsys power > dumpsys.power.screen_off.unlocked.txt`

5. Then use a text diffing tool (like winmerge) to look for differences between the `.txt` files.

Answer (score 2):

One adb command I'm using is:

`adb shell dumpsys window`

This returns a few system variables that are useful such as `mAwake`, `mShowingLockscreen`, `mScreenOnEarly`, `mScreenOnFully`.

To figure out which correspond to a locked/unlocked screen, I used `adb shell dumpsys window > <textFileNameOfYourChoice>`

tl;dr

The combination that I'm finding to be persistent is:

Device is locked AND screen is off:
`mAwake=false` AND `mShowingLockscreen=true`

Device is locked AND screen is on:
`mAwake=true` AND `mShowingLockscreen=true`

Device is unlocked AND screen is on:
`mAwake=true` AND `mShowingLockscreen=false`

Answer (score 2):

Attach a phone and run this code.

Press the power button, and see the changes that happen.

Unlock the phone and see the changes that happen.

Experiment. Have fun.

```
import re
import subprocess
import time

states = {
    'no_cached_wake_locks': '',
    'mDirty': '',
    'mWakefulness': '',
    'mWakefulnessChanging': '',
    'mIsPowered': '',
    'mPlugType': '',
    'mBatteryLevel': '',
    'mBatteryLevelCriticalLow': '',
    'mLastBatteryLevelCriticalLowTime': '',
    'mBatteryLevelWhenDreamStarted': '',
    'mDockState': '',
    'mStayOn': '',
    'mProximityPositive': '',
    'mBootCompleted': '',
    'mSystemReady': '',
    'mHalAutoSuspendModeEnabled': '',
    'mHalInteractiveModeEnabled': '',
    'mWakeLockSummary': '',
    'mUserActivitySummary': '',
    'mRequestWaitForNegativeProximity': '',
    'mSandmanScheduled': '',
    'mSandmanSummoned': '',
    'mLowPowerModeEnabled': '',
    'mBatteryLevelLow': '',
    'mLightDeviceIdleMode': '',
    'mDeviceIdleMode': '',
    'mScreenBrightnessBoostInProgress': '',
    'mDisplayReady': '',
    'mHoldingWakeLockSuspendBlocker': '',
    'mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker': '',
}


def checkit():
    cmd = ['adb', 'shell', 'dumpsys', 'power']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                        bufsize=0,
                        universal_newlines=True,
                        stdin=None,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    changes = 0
    for line2 in proc.stdout.readlines():
    line = line2.strip()
    for state, value in states.items():
        m = re.search(r'{}=(.*)'.format(state), line)
        if m:
            if value != m.group(1):
                changes += 1
                print("changed: state={} old={} new={}".format(state, value, m.group(1)))
                states[state] = m.group(1)
    if changes > 0:
    print("---- {} changes".format(changes))


while True:
    checkit()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

For exanple, these are the changes that happen after you lock the phone and the screen is black:

```
changed: state=mWakefulness old=Awake new=Asleep
changed: state=mHalAutoSuspendModeEnabled old=false new=true
changed: state=mHalInteractiveModeEnabled old=true new=false
changed: state=mUserActivitySummary old=0x4 new=0x0
changed: state=mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker old=true new=false
---- 5 changes
changed: state=mWakeLockSummary old=0x1 new=0x0
changed: state=mHoldingWakeLockSuspendBlocker old=true new=false
---- 2 changes
changed: state=mWakeLockSummary old=0x0 new=0x1
changed: state=mHoldingWakeLockSuspendBlocker old=false new=true
---- 2 changes
changed: state=mWakeLockSummary old=0x1 new=0x0
changed: state=mHoldingWakeLockSuspendBlocker old=true new=false
---- 2 changes
```

Answer (score 1):

Omitting the lock status ; things that work on Android 12 and 13 :

**IMPORTANT** : those return nothing after the device been restarted.
if the three commands below return "", use "adb shell input keyevent 26" and try again.

```
adb shell getprop debug.tracing.screen_state
```

"2" means screen ON
Note : Does NOT work on older Android versions (9, 10 .. )

```
adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep -i screenon
```

Result : "screenOn = false" or "screenOn = true"
Notes :
slower than other two commands (~2 sec)
does not work on all models; use the two other options in those case

```
adb shell dumpsys power | grep mWakefulness= | head -1
```

Screen ON gives *mWakefulness=Awake*
Notes :

- grep with "=" to avoid "mWakefulnessChanging"
- make sure to look for "=Awake" because some device return "Partial awake" just after screen turned off
- does not work on all models; use the two other options

Answer (score 0):

If its a rooted phone you can check some fields related to *lock* in settings.db.

settings.db is located at `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases`

Comment: I was looking for something that would work with rooted as well as non-rooted device. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

try `adb shell dumpsys window | grep mCurrentFocus | grep StatusBar`;

since all unlocked status(include wrong PIN) executed by this CMD return `mCurrentFocus=Window{343b978 u0 StatusBar}`

example like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if adb shell dumpsys window | grep mCurrentFocus | grep -q StatusBar; then
    echo 'phone is locked';
    exit 0;
fi

echo 'phone is unlocked'
```

By Android 10;

Answer (score 0):

Worked with my Galaxy Note + (Locked with passcode)

```
unlock() {
  if adb shell dumpsys window | grep mCurrentFocus | grep -n NotificationShade; then
     adb shell 'input keyevent 26 && input keyevent 82'
     if adb shell dumpsys window | grep mCurrentFocus | grep -n Bouncer; then
        echo "Device was locked"
        adb shell 'input text 12345678 && input keyevent 66'
     fi
  fi
}
```