# How to check if screen lock is enabled in the settings using adb

Tags: android, mobile, adb

I need to know how to check if any type of screen lock is enabled in the settings part of the device. I need to check this using an adb command (by using adb shell). I also need to know the type of lock applied.

I have tried dumpsys but did not get any success.

I want to know if the screen lock is enabled in the settings even if the device is currently unlocked, just check if any security is there, in any state.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275828/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-android-device-screen-is-locked-via-adb/49783208)? Look further below than the accepted answer.

Comment: I need to check for security password enabled even if the phone is currently unlocked

Answer (score 2):

Has answered in [Is there a way to check if Android device screen is locked via adb? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275828/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-android-device-screen-is-locked-via-adb/60037241#60037241) and copy to here:

- My Phone: `XiaoMi 9`

  - Android: `10`

## use adb to check status of screen locked

### method 1: (universal) use `mDreamingLockscreen`

- Command: `adb shell dumpsys window | grep mDreamingLockscreen`
- Output:

  - `mShowingDream=false mDreamingLockscreen=true mDreamingSleepToken=null` -> Screen **Locked**

    - no matter Screen is `ON` or `OFF`
  - `mShowingDream=false mDreamingLockscreen=false mDreamingSleepToken=null` -> Scrren **Unlocked**

### method 2: use `nfc` (if android has NFC module)

- Command: `adb shell dumpsys nfc | grep 'mScreenState='`
- Output:

  - `mScreenState=OFF_LOCKED` -> Screen OFF and Locked
  - `mScreenState=ON_LOCKED` -> Screen ON and Locked
  - `mScreenState=ON_UNLOCKED` -> Screen ON and Unlocked